# How To Enable Glamor On Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, opengl, hardware-acceleration, 2d

How do I enable **Glamor** mode which accelerates 2D graphics with OpenGL on Ubuntu?

See [Choose acceleration method](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#Choose_acceleration_method) on Arch Linux wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GLAMOR** is an acceleration library merged into the X.Org Server 1.16 that provides 2D acceleration implemented over OpenGL so X.Org DDX drivers no longer need to implement 2D-specific code-paths. GLAMOR is designed to be universal amongst OpenGL / OpenGL ES supported hardware.

For Trusty the package to install is:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl
```

And you also have to manually edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/glamoregl.conf` to enable it.

Source: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Glamor/